# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['embedding_1/embeddings:0', 'image_layer_1/kernel:0', 'image_layer_1/bias:0',

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

This is a program that generates captions for images and then updates the weights of the model based on the cross entropy loss. While updating the weights of the model, I come across this error and cannot figure out the root cause. Please guide me to fix this.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, feedback):
    # Compute cross-entropy loss
    cross_entropy_loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    # Compute negative feedback loss
    negative_feedback_loss = tf.reduce_mean(-1 * np.exp(feedback))
    # Combine both losses with a weighted sum
    total_loss = cross_entropy_loss + negative_feedback_loss
    return total_loss

# Define loss function and optimizer
loss_fn = custom_loss
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

# Update model parameters using RL algorithm
for img in os.listdir(dataset_images): # Number of RL iterations
    RL_learning_loop += 1
    if RL_learning_loop < 10:
        image_path = dataset_images + "/" + img
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        #image = image.resize(300,300)
        image.show()
        photo = extract_features(image_path, xception_model)
        in_text = 'start'
        for i in range(max_length):
            sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([in_text])[0]
            sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], maxlen=max_length)
            #preds = model.predict([photo,sequence], verbose=0)
            preds = model([photo,sequence])
            next_index = sample_pred(preds, temperature=0.5) # introduce randomness with temperature=0.5
            next_word = word_for_id(next_index, tokenizer)
            if next_word is None:
                break
            in_text += ' ' + next_word
            if next_word == 'end':
                break

        print("Generated caption:", in_text)
        
        feedback = float(input("Rate the quality of the caption (0-1): "))

        # Compute loss between predicted and ground-truth caption
        true_caption = get_true_caption(image_path, cln_descriptions) # function to get ground-truth caption
        true_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([true_caption])[0]
        true_sequence = pad_sequences([true_sequence], maxlen=max_length)
        y_true = np.zeros((1, max_length, len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1))
        for i, word_index in enumerate(true_sequence[0]):
            y_true[0, i, word_index] = 1
        y_pred = np.zeros((1, max_length, len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1))
        for i, word_index in enumerate(sequence[0]):
            y_pred[0, i, word_index] = 1
        loss = loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, feedback)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

        print("Loss: ",loss)

        trainable_vars = []
        for var in model.trainable_variables:
            if 'embedding' not in var.name and 'conv2d' not in var.name:
                trainable_vars.append(var)
                
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        print("Gradient",grads)
        print("**************************")
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, trainable_vars))

        # Update Q-table based on feedback
        for i in range(len(in_text.split())):
            word = in_text.split()[i]
            action = tokenizer.word_index[word]
            if i == len(in_text.split())-1:
                next_max_q_value = 0
            else:
                next_word = in_text.split()[i+1]
                next_action = tokenizer.word_index[next_word]
                next_max_q_value = np.max(q_table[i+1][next_action])
            q_table[i][action] += alpha * (feedback + gamma * next_max_q_value - q_table[i][action])

        # Save updated model and Q-table
        model.save('models/model_rl.h5')
        dump(q_table, open("q_table.p", "wb"))
```

The gradient is being calculated as

Gradient [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

and I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-6d5266f12187> in <cell line: 18>()
     64         print("Gradient",grads)
     65         print("**************************")
---> 66         optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, trainable_vars))
     67 
     68         # Update model weights based on loss

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/utils.py in filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
     75     if not filtered:
     76         variable = ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],)
---> 77         raise ValueError(
     78             f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "
     79             f"Provided `grads_and_vars` is {grads_and_vars}."

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['image_layer_1/kernel:0', 'image_layer_1/bias:0', 'LSTM_layer_1/lstm_cell_8/kernel:0', 'LSTM_layer_1/lstm_cell_8/recurrent_kernel:0', 'LSTM_layer_1/lstm_cell_8/bias:0', 'image_layer_2/kernel:0', 'image_layer_2/bias:0', 'LSTM_layer_2/kernel:0', 'LSTM_layer_2/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'image_layer_1/kernel:0' shape=(2048, 256) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.03491995, -0.04523179, -0.00278588, ...,  0.02073344,
```

Comment: The gradients are calculated as None. I am not sure, why is this happening.